# Can't opendir "No such file or directory" in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to send a file path from a text file into a varible. I then want to use that file path and open it and list the directories inside.

```
open (FILE, 'drive_path.txt') or die $!;
my $dir= (<FILE>);
close (FILE);
chomp $dir;
print $dir;
opendir (DIR, '$dir') or die $!;
```

The print output gives me the correct path location:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\KSoli7151794\Desktop\TEST
```

But for some reason, it says "No such file or Directory"
Any help?

EDIT: Here is the list of files on my Desktop:
 Volume in drive C is Operating System Drive
 Volume Serial Number is 18C9-6274

Directory of C:\Documents and Settings\KSoli7151794\Desktop

```
10/04/2013  11:35 AM    <DIR>          .
10/04/2013  11:35 AM    <DIR>          ..
11/18/2010  11:27 AM           587,776 7za.exe
10/04/2013  11:31 AM                51 drive_path.txt
10/03/2013  05:39 PM             1,494 ExtractAndCreate.bat
09/27/2013  04:34 PM               604 ExtractAndDelete.bat
10/04/2013  11:30 AM             1,854 ParseAndRename.pl
08/07/2013  11:38 AM    <DIR>          Resources
10/04/2013  11:06 AM    <DIR>          TEST
10/04/2013  11:35 AM                 0 test.txt
               8 File(s)        995,380 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  285,785,993,216 bytes free
```

New Code with Error Message:

```
open (FILE, 'drive_path.txt') or die $!;
my $dir= (<FILE>);
close (FILE);
chomp $dir;
print $dir;
opendir (DIR, $dir) or die $!;

C:\Documents and Settings\KSoli7151794\Desktop\TEST
Invalid argument at ParseandRename.pl line 18
```

First 18 lines

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (FILE, 'drive_path.txt') or die $!;
local $/;
my $blocksize;
my $directory;
my $testcase;
my $count = -1;
my @foldernames;
my @testsuite;
my $dir = (<FILE>);
close (FILE);
chomp $dir;
print $dir;
opendir (DIR, $dir) or die $!;
```

SOLUTION:
I took out `local$/;` and it seems to be working as intended.

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes prevent variable interpolation.  Your code tries to open a directory named `$dir` (dollar sign followed by the letter d, etc.). There is no need for them in your code:

```
opendir (DIR, $dir) or die $!;
```

This type of error can be detected by `perlcritic`:

> String *may* require interpolation at line ..., column 15.  See page
>   51 of PBP.  (Severity: 1)

UPDATE: Just try this single line:

```
opendir (DIR, 'C:\Documents and Settings\KSoli7151794\Desktop\TEST') or die $!;
```